# Jquery map hilight and rwd Image Maps not working together

Tags: jquery, dictionary, area

I have problem getting image map areas to highlight when hovered and on top of that i would like it to be responsive as well, i grabbed the responsive sample from [this](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html#blossom) page and added jquery map highlight.
Highlight works and resizes, but the image doesnt resize. I tried !important to overwrite the inline styles on img, but that didnt help. I also found [this](http://www.andensolutions.com/blog/responsiveImagePaths#comment-13029) tutorial coping with the same issue, but with their modified scripts the highlight didnt work at all.

Can anybody help me?

my testsite is here: 
http://design.imago.ee/test/map-area/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you might need to reduce the opacity of your image if it's not transparent, for that solution ([Responsive image maps with roll-overs](http://www.andensolutions.com/blog/responsiveImagePaths#comment-13029)) to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin I made combining both of those called [Map-Trifect](https://github.com/nswilhelm/jquery-map-trifecta). The image does not need its opacity adjusted.

You can test it [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6pukgLd/).

Simple to use:

```
$("img[usemap]").mapTrifecta();
```